# Use jQuery insertAfter in existing function that appends table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, append

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/JEAkX/1/

I am trying to get the appended cells to come after the last `tr`. Furthermore, I am attempting to change the `appendTable(id)` function so that the output cells have their content inside an `<input>` field like the original cells.

For the `<input>` addition I have tried:

Adding the input field code `<input type='text' size='1' value='subset[i++]' />` at various point with no luck I also tried it in another location but changed the value to `value='c'`.

For append after last tr I have tried:

Using jQuery and `.insertAfter('#alphabetTable tbody>tr:last')` I added it to various parts of the `cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(subset[i++]));` line but had no luck..probably the wrong placement?

I feel like I am sort of on the right track but lack the Javascript knowledge to know exactly where to insert the code and if surrounding code needs change.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be easier with JQuery but here's a hint:

```
function appendTable(id)
{
    var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var i = 0;
    var html = '<tr>';
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        html += '<td><input type="text" size="1"/></td>';
    }
    html += '</tr>';

    tbody.innerHTML += html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery:

```
var $tbody = $('#mytableid tbody:eq(0)');
var $tdLen = $('#mytableid tbody:eq(0) tr:eq(0) td').length; // cell length in row
$("<tr>").appendTo($tbody);
//append cells to row with input text
for (var i=0;i<$tdLen;i++){
    var inp = $("<input>").attr("type","text").attr("name","text"+i).val(i);
    var tdTemo = $("<td>");
    inp.appendTo(tdTemo);
    tdTemo.appendTo("tr:last");
}
```

this script will append row to table and add 4cells contain input type text :)

Comment: Omg, it told me about this response right after I posted:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254283/jquery-can-i-use-append-appendto-in-this-javascript-function do you think you could look at that one and tell me what you think?..I would prefer to delete this question as I was asking multiple questions in a poor way haha.